# "Unable to access" with move_uploaded_file() PHP

Tags: php

The function move_uploaded_file() isn't working on my server and I really dont know why.
the error:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to access MYADDRESS/img-19.png in MYADDRESS/index.php on line 660
```

I gave to the folder which I upload files chmod 777. any solution? im sure 100% the problem isn't in my code.

Comment: What's in $_POST?  Is there an error code?

Comment: There is nothing errors in the code. I think its a setting on the server.

Comment: Are you trying to move files using a URL path instead of FILESYSTEM path? You need to show us some code.

Comment: can we see some code? And I believe when you upload a file, it gives a temporary file name in the upload folder. Are you using that temp file name in move_uploaded_file? It is available in $_FILES["fieldName"]["tmp_name"]

Comment: Thank you very much all but the problem was as I said.. somthing in the server. I talked with the admin and he solved it. thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have it in the  `$src, $dest` order:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["field"]["tmp_name"], 'foo.png');
```

Also, check PHP settings, especially safe_mode and base dir restrictions.

Side note: Don't chmod your folders to be world writable! Change the group of the folder to be that of the webserver, and use 775. Last thing you need is something like an SQL injection from MySQL writing a PHP file into that folder.

Comment: And mode 664 for the files. Execute on .php files is a waste/overkill/risk